# Laravel get data from api by value

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel/Passport and already can get data by `id`:

**api.php/Controller.php**

```
Route::get('members/{member}', 'MemberController@show');

public function show(Member $member)
{
    return $member;
}
```

This just return all data by `id`, now I want to get member by phone number, so I created:

```
Route::get('members/{phone}', 'MemberController@phone');

public function phone(Member $member)
{
    return $member;
}
```

Error:

> exception:
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException" file:
>   "C:\Users\xx\xx\xx\xx\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php"
>   line: 204 message: "No query results for model [App\Member]
>   2929292222"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

route

```php
Route::get('members/{phone}', 'MemberController@phone');
```

controller

```php
public function phone(Member $member)
{
    return $member;
}
```

Go to `Member.php` `model`
and add this method `getRouteKeyName`

```php
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
  return 'phone';
}
```

Laravel by default it will automatically inject the model instance that has an ID matching the corresponding value from the request URI.

If you would like model binding to use a database column other than `id` when retrieving a given model class, **you may override the `getRouteKeyName` method on the Eloquent model:**

for more information check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#implicit-binding)